# WHMCS C# Authentication

Tags: c#, visual-studio, api, whmcs

I'm trying to develope a C# application to send an authentication request to the server. I can do it with php application being ran from a web browser but not using visual studio in a class.

I made a class which is suppose to declare what $whmcsUrl is. https://developers.whmcs.com/api/sample-code/ This is where i am trying to copy from.

My class looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace freeze_uk
{
    class whmcsUrl
    {
        whmcsUrl = "https://www.frezee.uk/client/";
    }
}
```

It says:

```
Error CS1519    Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
```

Why can't I use this?
Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Thanks,
James

Comment: Your concept is entirely wrong. I would suggest you to learn C# first, because your code ist just an syntax-mess. But if you want to go with it, you can try a HttpClient (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.7) to implement an request to your webserver.

Answer (score 1):

Add variable type 
string whmcsUrl = “....”